# adding controllers with a namespace admin as a subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

i have a simple cms on ROR 3.2.
with this folder scheme:

app |controllers |my controllers

but i wanted to have an "admin" section where i could have some controllers too.
so i created

> rails generate controller admin/Users

app | controllers |admin & my admin controllers

so my file is:

```
users_controller.rb
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render(:text => "sou o index!")
  end

  def list
    render(:text => "sou o list")
  end

end
```

On my routes i have:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users
  end

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Im new to rails and i cant figure out the solution. Cant find it anywhere.

The PROBLEM is
i try do acess:

> http://localhost:3000/admin/users/list

and i get this error:

> Unknown action The action 'show' could not be found for
>   Admin::UsersController

Comment: So, what's the actual problem?

Comment: What is your "list" action supposed to be doing? It's not a standard Rails REST action.

Comment: for debugging i just tried to render some text, but if i create a view.

Comment: views/admin/users/list.html.erb, and put out something to the browser, it gives me the same error. for localhost/admin/users, index is fine, and if i add a show method its all fine. but i dont know why when i go to localhost/admin/users/"something" the controller assumes that it got to be a show method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to not have an understanding of how Rails's RESTful routing works by default. I recommend reading the [Resource Routing section of the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). By default, when using `resources` in your routes, the `show` action is what is used to display a particular model record. You can [customize this behavior](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes) to an extent in that you can change the URL that for the `show` action, but not the method name in the model:

```
resources :users, :path_names => { :new => 'list' }
```

If you are going to use RESTful routing (which you should), you should remove the default route (`match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`). Also, you can run `rake routes` at any time from the terminal to see details about your current routing configuration.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. i will read some info about that because thats something i was curious about too. thanks.

Comment: those guides were really usefull. everything running according the expectations. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear, the guides don't go very in-depth in some places, but are a very good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track, however, there are a few more steps involved to complete your solution for a backend admin CRUD section. Check out the following example of how to create it yourself:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615003/2207480