# Rails create admin controller and view in other directory and with own style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I need to do own administration logic, with it's controllers, view etc... ActiveAdmin and so over are not good for me. But how can i do this in other directory (for example controllers/admin/). How to write then `rails g` command? (view must be in folder admin too). Also how to connect twitter bootstrap only for admin controllers?

Comment: Your question is too general and provides nothing to work off, have you tried anything yet? I recommend going through a [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).

Comment: @Knownasilya Let's start with non standart rails g scaffold.... How generate it for another directory with another stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this link, where they use the same [admin subdirectory grouping](http://www.purpleworkshops.com/articles/grouped-controllers) (link broken) example. The example is for an older version of Rails, but should be relatively valid for Rails 3.2.

**Edit:** See this [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245258/adding-controllers-with-a-namespace-admin-as-a-subfolder) question.

```
rails generate controller admin/Users
```

For bootstrap, just don't use the bootstrap specific id/class attributes in your admin stylesheet.